# Is html parser included in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I wrote the code

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://news.ycombinator.com/news')

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html_parser')
print(soup)
```

And the terminal returns

```
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: html_parser. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

There must be something I am doing wrong? Or is there something I forgot to install? I'm quite new to Beautiful Soup and data scraping in general so I'm open for advice and criticism.

Comment: List of parsers is found [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) including "html.parser" which is the one you're looking for.

Comment: [`html.parser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) from the standard library

Answer (score 0):

You wrote html parser wrong instead of `html_parser` it is `html.parser`

Your code should look like this:

```py
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://news.ycombinator.com/news')

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```